# What's not right in my View ? Xamdatagrid is not displaying the combo box data

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I would like to display data in products.xml in the xamDataGrid in MVVM style.Binding is not working properly. Values in the Product node must be added to combo box field in xamDatagrid. Combo box is not displaying any data. Can someone teach me how to fix this?

### Product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WG>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme2</TName>
    <Fname>fname2</Fname>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
    <Product>Product3 </Product>
    <Product>Product4 </Product>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme5</TName>
    <Fname>fname5</Fname>

  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
    <Product>Product3 </Product>
    <Product>Product4 </Product>
    <Product>Product5 </Product>
    <Product>Product6 </Product>

  </WGT>
</WG>
```

### products.cs [viewModel Class]

```
namespace XmlTest.ViewModel
{
        public partial class WG : ViewBase
    {

        private WGWGT[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WGT", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public WGWGT[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        public void display()
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WG));

            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\xlf\products.xml");
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            WG XmlData = (WG)obj;
            itemsField = XmlData.Items;



        }
    }

    public partial class WGWGT : ViewBase
    {

        private string tNameField;

        private string fnameField;

        private WGWGTProduct[] productField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string TName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Fname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fnameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Product", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true)]
        public WGWGTProduct[] Product
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class WGWGTProduct : ViewBase
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### View.xml

```
<Grid>
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="dataGridView1" DataSource="{Binding Items}"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="800" Margin="10,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800">

            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings >
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>

            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts >
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields >
                        <igDP:Field Label="Template Name" Name="TName" />
                        <igDP:Field Label="File Name" Name="Fname"/>


                        <igDP:UnboundField Label="Product Name" >
                            <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" AllowEdit="True">
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Product}"  />
                                            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value" />




                                        </Style>
                                    </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings>
                            </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                        </igDP:UnboundField>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

### View.xaml.cs

```
public partial class View : Window
        {
            public View()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                WaferGen wg = new WaferGen();
                this.DataContext = wg;
                wg.display();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I'm able to figure out the solution. I'm posting it here so that it can help someone like me.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}}, Path=Record.DataItem.Product}" />
                                            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value" />
```